# How to Check children before delete in rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have multiple mother child relatinships in my rails app. I would like to have one code which can handle this for all the mother child relations. Can anyone help?

Example
I have a model called project which has many tasks. A task belongs to one project. Also I have a model called timesheet which has many enties. An entry belongs to one timesheet. I have a lot of these mother child relationships.

I need one code which do this. Before deleting a mother e.g a project, look if there are any childs related to it, e.g tasks. If there are any tasks related show a popup screen saying are you sure you want to delete, there are 3 tasks related. 3 is the ammount of tasks found. If you say no, it does not delete the mother. If there are no tasks found you should be able to delete without a pop up screen.if there are tasks found you should never be able to delete the project. You should delete the related tasks first.

The code should work for all the mother child relations. So also for timesheets and entries etc.

I need this code because anytime i delete a mother which has children, all my apps break down. Where do i need to put the code to work for all mother and child relations in the app?

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

For a "popup" you can have your view output some simple client-side/javascript to show @project.tasks.length. You can use unobtrusive javascript and do something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', @project, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>
```

Also, if you are using a habtm relationship in your model, I've found I need to add a callback to clear the records in the join table to avoid orphaned records:

```
before_destroy {|project| project.tasks.clear}
```

Comment: Hi, still no success. Do you think this will work?                class Project < ActiveRecord::Base  
 before_destroy :check_tasks    
private     
def check_tasks 
if Project.find(params[:id]).tasks  
     flash[:notice] = 'This project has tasks.'

redirect_to :action => 'list_projects'    
  end 
end

Comment: Something like that should work, although you'll need to add an error to the form to prevent it being submitted, so rather than flash[:notice], try project.errors.add(:tasks, 'has tasks')